# Fluid layout background 100% wide with 50px padding on each side

Tags: css

Ok so I need to add a background image to repeat 100%, but I need to margins on each side.

```
******************************************
*    *                              *    *
* 50 *                              * 50 *
* px * This background image should * px *
*    * repeat-x 100% minus 100px.   *    *
*    *                              *    *
******************************************
```

Comment: and @Victor [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) ? consider adding a jsfiddle link to what and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a div within the div. That way you can apply the background to the second div and let the first div worry about margin.

```
#div1 {
    margin: 0 50px;
}

#div2 {
    background: url('XXX') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Please note: background-size is a CSS3 property and is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+.

Alternatively use:

```
#div {
    background: url('XXX') repeat-x;
    margin: 0 50px;
}
```

It isn't as good practice and I'm unsure which is the best solution depending on if your background is a colour/pattern or an image. Use the latter solution if it is not an image.

Comment: Thanks! However I need the legacy support down to IE7.

Comment: So what about solution 2, is it an image you are using?

Comment: I'm using three images: One on each side and one in the middle that needs to be fluid.